# An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Extensions.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#

Why do have this error on this part of the code ?

this part

```
           var data = serializer.Deserialize<EmailTemplate>(httpRequest.Form["data"].ToString());
```

my procedure

```
public int UpdateEmailTemplate()
    {

        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        ObjectService uploadFile = new ObjectService();
        List<ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Attachment> attachment = new List<ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Attachment>();

        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

        if (httpRequest.Form["data"] != null)
        {
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var data = serializer.Deserialize<EmailTemplate>(httpRequest.Form["data"].ToString());

            if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var docfiles = new List<string>();
                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
                    httpRequest.Files[file].InputStream.CopyTo(target);

                    uploadFile.AddObject(data.Id, "SU_ENTITY_MSG_TEMPLATE","", target.GetBuffer(), httpRequest.Files[file].FileName);
                }
            }

            AdminService List = new AdminService();
            return List.UpdateEmailTemplate(data);
    }
```

MY class

```
public class EmailTemplate
{
   public int Id;
   public string TypeObject;
   public int? idObject;
   public string ObjectName;
   public string IdTeam;
   public string IdTask;
   public string Team;
   public string task;
   public string Title;
   public string Subject;
   public string dataHtml;
   public List<Objects> fileListRequest;
}
```

Comment: Please show the details of the exception and the definition of `EmailTemplate`.

Comment: I do juste have this error messag {"Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array."} i have tried with {get;set} but it doesn't work

Comment: Most probably the string you are trying to deserialize does not match the definition of `EmailTemplate`. Are you trying to deserialize from JSON? Please show the string which cannot be deserialized; please try to find a string of minimum length which causes the error in discussion.

Comment: i do have this string "{\"Id\":50021,\"TypeObject\":\"Team\",\"idObject\":null,\"ObjectName\":\"Dep/arr missions\",\"IdTeam\":\"4\",\"IdTask\":null,\"Team\":null,\"task\":null,\"Title\":\"SWA\",\"Subject\":\"SWA\",\"dataHtml\":\"<p>x&lt;yx</p>\\n\",\"fileListRequest\":[],\"

Comment: Do you get the same error if you remove `fileListRequest` from the definition of `EmailTemplate`?

Comment: yes i do have the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty plainly saying that the contents of:

```
httpRequest.Form["data"]
```

...is an array of some sort. Adding .ToString() will just return it's type name. Passing that to Deserialize is what's giving you the error, as Deserialize is expecting an array and just getting a string.

Try taling the .ToString() off - this may not work. If it doesn't you'll have to convert httpRequest.Form["data"] to what ever data type you've put into it (whuich you do not say).

Comment: Then, as I say: "you'll have to convert httpRequest.Form["data"] to what ever data type you've put into it (whuich you do not say)."